# How to change color of linkbutton when clicked(visited link)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change on of my linkbutton's text color to red when a user clicks on the link. Therefore, as a user I can identify that I've already clicked on this link.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="FileGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="FileGrid_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalFileName" HeaderText="OriginalFileName" SortExpression="OriginalFileName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AttachmentGUID" HeaderText="AttachmentGUID" SortExpression="AttachmentGUID" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Generate_PDF" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF" CommandName="GeneratePDF_Click" CommandArgument="<%#Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
</form>
```

This is what I've tried using javascript.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('Generate_PDF').onclick = function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Use css instead :visited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    document.getElementById('Generate_PDF').onclick = function () {
        this.style.color= '#ff0000';
    };
```

Because you need to change the color of text, not the background.